# Reorder a column of a dataframe by factor() and using variable from argparse

Tags: r, rscript

I am using [argparse](https://github.com/trevorld/r-argparse) library to build a boxplot with [ggpubr](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr) library from command line interface. I can reorder particular column of my interest manually. 
However, I want to reorder particular column using argparse. 
I cannot figure it out, how to use **df$args$reorder** name.

Somehow, I need to automatize the line

```
df$Population <- factor(df$Population, levels = c("Control", "American"))
```

to

```
get(args$reorder, df) <- factor(get(args$reorder, df), levels = c(args$new_order))
```

or

```
df$args$reorder <- factor(df$args$reorder, levels = c(args$new_order)
```

Here is the code I have tried

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Rscript

suppressWarnings(library(argparse))
suppressWarnings(library(ggpubr))

parser <- ArgumentParser(description="Tools for making plot from command line") 

parser$add_argument("--file", type="character", help="Input file")
parser$add_argument("--x-ax", type="character", help="x_axis value")
parser$add_argument("--y-ax", type="character", help="y_axis value")
parser$add_argument("--color", type="character", help="color by")
parser$add_argument("--facet-col", type="character", default=NULL, help="facet by")
parser$add_argument("--reorder", type="character", default=NULL, help="reorder a column")
parser$add_argument("--new_order", type="character", default=NULL, help="new orders for the items")

args <- parser$parse_args()

df <- read.csv(args$file)

head(df)
#Population  Diet BloodPressure
#1   American Vegan           167
#2   American Vegan           160
#3   American Vegan           162
#4   American Vegan           165
#5   American Vegan           159
#6   American Vegan           177

#The line below can manually reorder the items in the column.
#df$Population <- factor(df$Population, levels = c("Control", "American"))

# I want to do something like this
#get(args$reorder, df) <- factor(get(args$reorder, df), levels = c(args$new_order))


fig <- ggboxplot(df, x = args$x_ax , y = args$y_ax, 
facet.by = args$facet_col, fill = args$color, palette = "npg")

ggsave("reorder_factor.png")
```

The data I used is [here](http://freetexthost.com/h6rgknc32w)

Before reordering the [image is like the following](https://i.postimg.cc/JnfvLngJ/reorder-factor.png)

and after reordering [image is like following](https://i.postimg.cc/4yRL007Q/reorder-factor.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks!
I solved it by accidental trial and error.

```
df[[args$reorder]] <- factor(df[[args$reorder]], levels = args$new_order)
```

Although I don't know how does this work.
Happy coding.